# Using Coordinate layout listview shows only first item in Preview

Tags: android, listview

I am using listview with nestedscrollview and coordinatelayout,but when i see in preview of design layout it shows first item of listview,and also when i run app it shows first item,following is my XML can any one tell what is the issue

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarsubcat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lvsubcategory"
                android:divider="#ffffff"
                android:dividerHeight="10dp"

                />


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Remove nested scrollview.

Comment: no change..stiill same result

Comment: refresh view in Preview after change ( 3rd last button on Preview screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarsubcat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvsubcategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have Removed Nested scroll & added this line to Listview : 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  after that refresh view in Preview.

Comment: listview is displaying now,,but my toolbar is steady...then how can i hide??

Comment: onscroll my toolbar is not hiding now

Comment: show your activity. I want to see code for  hiding toolbar.

Comment: this will hide the toolbar app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: You can get full knowledge about material design just go through this link:https://github.com/bsuhas/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101396/discussion-between-jolly-and-suhas-b).