# Android ListView displays only first element of List<string passed to it

Tags: android, listview

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private List<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> events, Context context) {
        this.events = events;
        this.context = context;
        String a = String.valueOf(events.size());
        Toast.makeText(context,a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return events.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //return events.get(position).getId();
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
        }

        TextView listtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label1);
        listtv.setText(events.get(position));

        Button delbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.del_button);

        delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You didn' code this feature yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

> I am creating an object of MyAdapter and calling it by passing a List and Activity.this
>   when i try to toast the size of the list passed i get the proper size
>   however only the first item of the list gets displayed on the screen

MY Xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#00000000">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
    >

</TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/del_button"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        >
       </Button>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

and my main layout file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_cal_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.test123.CalView"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cal_view">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281863/listview-only-shows-first-item and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833834/android-listview-only-show-the-first-result

Comment: xml Please?????????/

Comment: We need your AXML file with your layout.

Comment: @jeremy are you using Listview inside a  ScrollView?

Comment: @UsmanRana No the List view is inside a relative layout

Comment: can you paste your xml here? i believe that issue should be there.

Comment: just added my XML here

Comment: replace your method with this in adapter. why are you forcing it to 0?
public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

Comment: i wasn't interested in getting Id, so i did it that way. Replacing that with return position doesnt help me

Comment: check this similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945367/using-coordinate-layout-listview-shows-only-first-item-in-preview

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView listTV;
        public Button delButton;

    }      



@Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);

        //Edited this part
holder = new ViewHolder
                holder.listTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label1);

                holder.delbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.del_button);

     view.setTag(holder);
            } else holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

                listtv.setText(events.get(position));

                delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"You didn' code this feature yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                return view;
            }
```

Comment: I edited my answer a bit! Did you tried the edited one!

Comment: @HsRaja, thanks for the links. my problem was being caused by the nested scroll view not filling the viewport

Comment: Thank you everyone else for trying to help